# What's Wrong? initialized module 'pyperclip' has no attribute 'paste' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am facing an output issue with my code which is attached with output.

```
    import webbrowser, sys, pyperclip
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        #Get address from command line.
        address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    else:

        #Get address from clipboard.
         address = pyperclip.paste()
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Output:  text = pyperclip.paste()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyperclip' has no attribute 'paste' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Is this code complete as shown, or does some other module import it?

Comment: It is a complete code, I have installed pip3 and necessary module but getting the error on output. why I can't understand?

Comment: What filename is this code saved as?

Comment: it is saved as trial.py

Comment: The error message refers to the line `text = pyperclip.paste()`, but your code has `address = pyperclip.paste()`, so this isn't your actual code.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other scripts that are named `pyperclip.py` that may be imported accidentally.

Comment: that's exactly happened, thank you so much. now the output is correct.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct but the pyperclip.py file exists in the same directory, later on, removed file, and able to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to name the Python file the same as any of the modules being imported in that Python file. so rename the python file and then it should work perfectly fine